# Prove $ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Prove $ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.
I know how to do it using calculus. But I want to use Cauchy's integral formula.

First, consider $ \oint_C e^{-z^2} dz$ along a contour C consisting of a line along the x-axis from $-R$ to $R$ and the semicircle $\Gamma$ above the x-axis having this line as diameter.

By Cauchy's Integral formula $ \oint_C e^{-z^2} dz=0$ which implies

$ \int_{-R}^{R} e^{-x^2} dx + \int_{\Gamma} e^{-z^2} dz=0$.

When $R \to \infty$, $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx + \int_{\Gamma} e^{-z^2} dz=0$.

Now to compute $\int_{\Gamma} e^{-z^2} dz$, consider $z=Re^{i \theta}$, $dz=iRe^{i \theta}$.

I am stuck here.

Comment: This method will fail, as $e^{-z^2}$ has no singularities. The integral can be done by contour integration but with a great deal of cunning. Integrate $\exp(i\pi z^2)/\sin(\pi z)$ over the boundary of the parallelogram with vertices $\pm(1/2)\pm e^{i\pi/4}R$.

Comment: Note the essential singularity for $\exp$ at $\infty$ and so $\Gamma_1$ picks up the residue term once you make the transformation $w=1/z^2$.

Comment: You have a problem: in the whole upper half plane, $z^2$ has a real part with either sign, so there is no decay at infinity. Thus you have reduced the problem to directly evaluating the integral along the circular arc. But this isn't actually any easier than the problem you started with; actually it's probably *harder* than the problem you started with.

Comment: @AnginaSeng you don't need to integrate along a sneaky parallelogram.  You can integrate a suitable function on a rectangle to get this. See Section 10 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf.

Comment: See a discussion of this very question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/105457/454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some guidelines (from Freitag - Complex Analysis) to prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$$ using the complex Residue theorem. If you want more details just ask.

Define $$f(z) = \frac{\exp(-z^2)}{1 + \exp(- 2 a z)}$$ where $a = e^{2 \pi i/4}\sqrt{\pi}$. We will perform contour integration on the parallelogram with vertices $[-R, R, R+a, -R+a]$ and let $R \to \infty$.

(A) Derive the functional identity $$f(z) - f(z + a) = \exp(-z^2)$$

(B) Find the poles of $f(z)$.

> Check $a/2$. That is the only one.

(C) Use the ML inequality to estimate away the diagonal edges. Using the functional identity to match up the bottom and reverse of the top edge.

(D) Use Residue theorem to conclude.

> The residue of the pole is $\tfrac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\pi}$

---

Edit: Just to amplify one of the comments above. My first time seeing this but it can also be done over a rectangle via the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{1 - e^{- \sqrt{\pi} (1 + i) z}}$$ page 8 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (probably) way to derive the stated identity might be resorting to polar coordinates. Let us denote $$ I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx,$$ our goal is to show that $ I = \sqrt{\pi}$. We compute as follows:
\begin{align*}
I^2 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{e}^{-(x^2+y^2)} dxdy \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-r^2} rdrd\theta \\
&= \frac 12\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta = \pi,
\end{align*}
whence $I = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Comment: OP is already aware of this method

Comment: Stein has a book titled "Complex Analysis", the Example 1 in Chapter 2 contains a proof (using contour integration) of a more general identity which easily gives rise to the desired result.